# How to avoid the ugly "boxes" when child views in a View has another color than the background (stateful drawables for example)

Tags: android

I have a simple ListView and on that ListView I have placed a number of custom defined Views. The CustomView has ImageView and two TextViews.

The CustomView also has a "stateful drawable" as background, so that the background image (a 9-patch) changes if you press the Row in the ListView. When pressing the Row, the background image changes to a Red-ish thing.

**The problem** is that when the background changes from the default greyish, all the Views in the CustomView (ImageView and TextViews) still have their greyish background and thus creates very ugly greay boxes on top of the now redish background.

What is the best way to solve that problem? I hoped that such things were handled automatically (as it is done in for example .NET), but I was wrong it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it =)

You can use the color "transparent"

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Set the Views with that color, and its all good =)